# Limit of sequence of sets

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a sequence of sets $(S_k)$. What could be the condition for $S_\infty$ (the one taken at infinity) to be subset of, or be equal to, the limit $\limsup S_k$ of the sequence?

Eg: $S_k = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x/k = 0\}$. With this, $S_k = \{0\}$ for all $k$ and the sequence converges to this set, but $S_\infty = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $\infty$ is not a number, so $x/\infty$ makes no sense. What exactly do you mean by $S_\infty$?

Answer (score 0):

The condition is that $\lim \sup 1_{S_k}(x) = 1_{S_\infty}(x)$ where $1_{S_k}(x)$ is the indicator function of $S_k$

Comment: Thanks. How do you show that? Looks like that’s what I need. Is the characteristics function continuous with respect to its input set?

Comment: @Hello no, the indicator function only take either $1$ or $0$ as its value so it can't be continous. So the statement as I mentioned can be understood as "For each $x$, there exists a number $n_0$ such that $\forall n>n_0, \sup_{m \geq n} 1_{S_m}(x) =1_{ S_\infty}(x)$